# Fresh install Ubuntu 16.04.1 unable to detect dmraid disk

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, 16.04, raid, dmraid

I'm using a BIOS raid1 with Marvell chipset which works really well with dmraid in Ubuntu 14.04.

The disk is shown as the following name with command `fdisk`:

```
Disk /dev/mapper/ddf1_00000000000000004b1b92914b1b92914b0400004b040001: 2000.3 GB, 2000315047936 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243191 cylinders, total 3906865328 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3b9fee89

                                                         Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/ddf1_00000000000000004b1b92914b1b92914b0400004b040001p1            2048  3906865151  1953431552   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/ddf1_00000000000000004b1b92914b1b92914b0400004b040001p1: 2000.3 GB, 2000313909248 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243190 cylinders, total 3906863104 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ddf1_00000000000000004b1b92914b1b92914b0400004b040001p1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

However, after I do a fresh install to Ubuntu 16.04 the disk is detected as `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`. Mounting these hard drives only get error with unknown type `ddf_raid_member`. Installing `dmraid` doesn't help either. Using command `sudo dmraid -ay` only returns no raid disk.

But luckily, I'm still able to access the raid device with Ubuntu 14.04 Live CD. How can I make the raid device work again in 16.04? Thanks!

**Update 2016/07/26**

I've rolled back to Ubuntu 14.04. The fakeRaid device is still able to work normally. Does this means that Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't support dmraid correctly?

**Update 2016/08/06**

I've tried to install `mdadm` in Ubuntu 16.04.1, but `mdadm` only tells me that the hard drives does not have superblocks and cannot be reconstructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reported to the launchpad and got fix by the developer. The bug seems to be related the new feature of the 4.4 kernel.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1611277

But the new version of dmraid is not guaranteed on every devices. At least it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to get a better answer. For now, you have to run

```
sudo dmraid -ay
```

from the BusyBox prompt or go live with the disc, run it terminal, then install to the array.

To get it into the boot sequence make a text file in

```
/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount
```

with the code

```
exec dmraid -ay
exec sleep 1
```

Ensure that you make the file executable then run

```
sudo update initramfs -k all -uv
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks but I've tried this before. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solved by installing raid support.
Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install mdadm
```

Comment: Thanks. But I've tried before, mdadm said my fakeRaid does not have superblocks and cannot reconstruct the hard drives.